# How do I get object in else part?

Tags: javascript

If the object is not in an array then I'm setting an id and pushing that object in array otherwise I'm updating an array. But to update an array I need an id and to get that id I need an object in else part. Now how do I get the object in else part? 
HELP

This is what I've done in else part:

```
let obj = dataArray.find(d => d.id === id) // how do I get object? 
let index = dataArray.findIndex(d=>d.id === obj.id)
selectedIndex = index
dataArray.splice(selectedIndex, 1, obj);



let selectedIndex = -1
let dataArray = []
let obj = {
    na: 'preyash'    ,
    ge: 'male'  ,
    ho: 'cricket' ,
    em: 'phionn@mail.com'   ,
    ph: '8460811891'   ,
    ac: 'action'
}];

if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    obj.id = new Date().getTime();
    dataArray.push(obj);
} else {
    let obj = dataArray.find(d => d.id === id)
    let index = dataArray.findIndex(d=>d.id === obj.id)
    selectedIndex = index
    dataArray.splice(selectedIndex, 1, obj);
}
```

The task is to get the object from an id.

Comment: What you want `id` to be in else part. Because `id` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I just want an index and that index I have to get from an id.

Comment: That's my question, mate. I've defined id in if part 'obj.id = new Date().getTime();' but how do I get id in else part?

Comment: Simply use `obj.id`. And also you are not creating copy of `obj`. Try changing `dataArray.push(obj);` to `dataArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`

Comment: Mate, obj.id won't work because in else part I don't have an id.

Comment: But you have `obj` available in else part.

Comment: let obj = dataArray.find(d => d.id === id) this line ain't working

Comment: Do you understand the dilemma?